# Will react-hook-form work without the name prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have seen this example in the react-hook-form documentation https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register `Custom onChange, onBlur`

```
const firstName = register('firstName', { required: true })
<input 
  onChange={(e) => {
    firstName.onChange(e); // method from hook form register
    handleChange(e); // your method
  }}
  onBlur={firstName.onBlur}
  ref={firstName.ref} 
/>
```

Here there is no `name="firstName"` inside `<input>`

So will this work without mentioning name prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` is required, how else could RHF know what field the value belong to? The code in the docs is missing the `name` prop. You can confirm that the code doesn't work if you omit it:

```
<input
  // without the line below you can't see the submitted value
  name={firstName.name}
  onChange={(e) => {
    firstName.onChange(e); // method from hook form register
    handleChange(e); // your method
  }}
  onBlur={firstName.onBlur}
  ref={firstName.ref}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with problem of RHF not working without the *name* prop, however, in the documentation of the current version (7.13.0), code examples are already without the *name* prop. Updating the version solved the problem for me. Validation delay also started working (the *delayError* option in the useForm hook)